# JQuery select input value doesn't change automatically if you set by hands

Tags: jquery, select, text, input, range

I have select and input range + input text.

There are two types of choices in select:

1. Your size in inputs value.
2. Fixed size in inputs value.

If you choose fixed size everything is ok but, if you set size by hands at first and then choose fixed size input value doesn't changed. Where is the mistake?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {     
        $("div.roword select").change( function() {
            var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
            if (text == "60x90") {
                $("input#height, input#heightPlus").attr('value', '60');
                $("input#width, input#widthPlus").attr('value', '90');
                $("input#height, input#width").focus();
                $("input#height, input#width").blur();
             }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant HTML?

Comment: Add some `HTML` or reproduce the problem in the snippet if possible.

Comment: It's hard to understand your issue. It may help if you could add the HTML to your question in a working snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
    $("div.roword select").change( function() {
        var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        if (text == "Size 60x90") {
            $("input#height, input#heightPlus").val(60);
            $("input#width, input#widthPlus").val(90);
            $("input#height, input#width").focus();
            $("input#height, input#width").blur();
        }
   });
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  count = 0;
     var html2 = $("<input form='send' type='range' id='width' name='width" + count + "' min='40' max='300' value='40'/><input type='text' pattern='\d*' maxlength='3' id='widthPlus' name='widthPlus" + count + "' min='40' max='300' value='40'/>");
     $(".form-col-3").html(html2);
  $(document).on('input', '#width', function(event) {
      $(this).next().val($(this).val());
  });
  $(document).on('input', '#widthPlus', function(event) {
      $(this).prev().val($(this).val());
  });
  $("div.roword select").change( function() {
         var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
         if (text == "Size 60x90") {
             $("input#height, input#heightPlus").val(60);
             $("input#width, input#widthPlus").val(90);
             $("input#height, input#width").focus();
             $("input#height, input#width").blur();
         }else{
             $("input#height, input#heightPlus").val(40);
             $("input#width, input#widthPlus").val(40);                
            }
    });
    });
```

```html
<div id="form" >
       <div class="roword">
           <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-col-1">
               <select  form="send" name="type[]">
                    <option value="">Choose type</option>
                    <option class="optionBold" value="1.1">Your own size</option>
                   <option value="1.1">Size 60x90</option>
                  </select>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 form-col-3">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-5 col-xs-10 form-col-4">
               <input class="myPrice" form="send" type="text" name="result[]" readonly>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for help and responsiveness! .val() works great. Second part with counter doesn't work but I've just understood how to do. I'd returned inputs to .php file with html code added there id and names[] (array) also added your jquery code which takes value of one input to another to script. Everything is great. Thanks one more time.